# Como validar jtextfield en java para que acepte solo números?

Tags: java, jtextfield

Una pregunta, como valido un *Jtextfield* de java sin usar el *keyTyped* para que solo me acepte números, no deseo utilizar *KeyTyped*, necesito otra alternativa de validar para que solo acepte numeros.

Comment: que numeros? enteros, decimales, negativos ... ?

Comment: @lois6b vaya creo que respondi muy rapido, no analice muy bien como tu lo planteas, deberia eliminar mi respuesta?

Comment: Que tienes realizado en código?

Answer (score 3):

Aquí tienes [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102916/3045491) muy buena que te plantea éstos métodos:

- Una funcion que intente convertir el `String` en un `Double`.

  ```
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
        try
        {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {  
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
  ```
- Una regular expresion. Incluye el simbolo "-" para negativos y para decimales (con ".") . Si se quisiera con "," para decimal, sustituir el punto del parámetro de `matches`.

  ```
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
      return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  
    }
  ```
- Usando la librería de Java java.text.NumberFormat

  ```
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        formatter.parse(str, pos);
        return str.length() == pos.getIndex();
    }
  ```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Le sugiero editar la llave de cierre para que quede dentro de la estructura de código. Yo intenté hacerlo pero al guardar, el sistema detecta que no hubo cambios y no me permite guardar los cambios.

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa seria usar codigo **ascii** https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII revisa los codigos http://ascii.cl/es/

la parte que nos interesa es los numeros:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo tanto en codigo seria:

```
if(datoCharIngresado>=48 && datoCharIngresado<=57)
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Por qué no utilizas `JFormattedTextField`? Es muy fácil de usar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
    formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
    formatter.setMinimum(0); //valor mínimo
    formatter.setMaximum(Integer.MAX_VALUE); //valor máximo
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    // Si quieres comprobar que sea válido, cada vez que se pulse una tecla
    formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
    JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, field);

    //Para recoger el valor del JFormattedTextField --> field.getValue();
}
```