# ¿Que tipo de código me aceptaría para que me ingrese solo números en un TextField?

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans-8.2

Que solo sea menor de 8 números y que no acepte otro tipo de carácter

Comment: hola por favor lee [ask] y de paso haz el [tour] la comunidad con gusto te ayudará; pero no es solo decir como se hace tal cosa, también es mostrar que haz intentado y que errores haz tenido

Comment: Esta bien, gracias

Comment: Debe validar tañamo y tipo

Comment: Quizás te pueda ayudar esta pregunta anterior: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44461/como-validar-jtextfield-en-java-para-que-acepte-solo-n%C3%BAmeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes validar a través de [actionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) para gatillar la validación, y verificar el input con [expresiones regulares](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

### TextValidation:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TextValidation extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextField data;

    public TextValidation() {
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 10, 10));

        data = new JTextField(15); 
        c.add(data);

        c.add(new JLabel("Ingresa numero entre 1 y 8 largo"));
        c.add(data);
        
        data.addActionListener(this);
        
        setSize(350, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str1 = data.getText(); 
        
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,8}");
        
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(str1); 

        if (m.matches()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "valido"); 
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "invalido");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TextValidation();
    }
}
```

La expresión de validación es la siguiente:

```
\\d{1,8}
```

Significa que va a buscar solo dígitos de largo 1 a 8 (incluidos)

### Ejemplos:

[image: Valido]

[image: Inválido]

[image: Inválido]

Comment: Hola @Rcordoval. Puesto que el usuario que pregunta es nuevo, deberías esperar a que edite su pregunta como se le ha dicho en los comentarios. Responder a este tipo de pregnutas no es beneficioso para el sitio.

Comment: Tienes razón @PabloSimonDiEstefano. ¿Debería eliminar mi respuesta?

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar un MaskFormatter y un JFormattedTextField en vez de un JTextField.

```
MaskFormatter formato = new MaskFormatter("########");
JFormattedTextField campo = new JFormattedTextField(formato);
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el siguiente código el cuál permitirá que el usuario sea capaz de ingresar únicamente números, es decir, bloqueará cualquier otra tecla que sea presionada, además de no permitir el uso de más de 8 caracteres.Sólo modifica la variable "cajaTexto" por el nombre de la variable que tú le asignaste a tu TextField al momento de crearlo.

```
    cajaTexto.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{
        //Se asigna al valor anterior
        if(!newValue.matches("[0-9]{0,8}") || newValue.length()>8){
            ((StringProperty) observable).setValue(oldValue);
        }else{
            //Se asigna el nuevo valor, porque sí coincide con la expresión
            ((StringProperty)observable).setValue(newValue);
        }
    });
```